# Mixing sync and async javascript/jquery and getting a success function at the end

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Wondering what the best solution to this problem is, also this is not my actual code structure or names but the simplest way to illustrate the problem. 
I have a function which was purely used to perform an ajax call and load a template with jquery.

```
function load(template) {
    $('#container').load(template, data, function() {
       // complete code here
    }); 
}
```

Focusing on the 3rd param in $.load(), namely a callback function that runs when the request is complete.

Now I have my load() function in another wrapper function:

```
function processTask(variable) {
    load(variable);
}
```

The problem I have is I need some code to run after the ajax load is complete, however as my app has grown my wrapper function `processTask` may or may not invoke an ajax `load` so I can't perform my must needed code inside the complete callback.

Do I change my $.load() to perform synchronous or just manage my code better so that if I am calling a $.load() it puts my needed code in the callback and if not it places it where I need it to be?

I have read about javascript Promises and I'm unsure if they will help in this situation.

EDIT

So my `processTask` is an object method.

```
function classObj(name, fn) {
    this.name = name;
    this.processTask = fn;
    this.load = function(template) {
        $('#container').load(template, data, function() {
           // complete code here
        });
    }
}
```

And in context I do this:

```
var task = new classObj('taskName', function() {  
    this.load('myFile.php'); 
    // Or another function and not load() based on whats needed in the task. 
});
```

Basically I have an object that I can add custom methods to at will and they can easily be called dynamically, until now they have always loaded a file.

Comment: _"processTask may or may not invoke an ajax load so I can't perform my must needed code inside the complete callback"_ Can include logic of `processTask` at "may or may not invoke an ajax load" at Question ?

Comment: `And in context I do this:` ... the load function you define accepts no parameters ... the code you've posted is quite confusing. What is the significance (if any) of `this.name`, `this.processTask` to the question? Can you simplify the code to just the part you're having a problem with, and at least TRY to show the flow logic ... putting a comment like "or another function" really doesn't help

Comment: Apologies for the confusing code, my actual code is far more complex and has many layers to the object so I was not able to simply post an example of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, change your `load` function to return the xhr from `get` (or `ajax`):

```
function load(template) {
    return $.get('myFile.php', data, function(result) {
       $('#container').html(result);
    }); 
}
```

Then, within your code you can use `when` `then` to perform your code after the load completes if applicable:

```
var xhr;

/* ... */

if(something){
     xhr = load(template);
}

/* ... */

if(xhr){
    $.when(xhr).then(doSomething);
} else {
    doSomething();
}
```

And in fact, this can be simplified using the fact that a non-deferred object passed to `when` (including undefined apparently) will execute the `then` immediately and get rid of the if:

```
$.when(xhr).then(doSomething);
```

If `xhr` is undefined then `when` will resolve immediately causing `then` to execute immediately.

Comment: @guest271314 Good point.  `load` needs to be changed to something that returns an xhr like `get` or `ajax`.  Answer updated.